# SSRS Export Formatting

Tags: reporting-services

I have text box labels on the left, a single line table (filtered) in the middle, and another single line table on the right.  Repeat this multiple times down the page.  I have selected the top row of them and aligned tops.  I have selected each group of tables and removed vertical spacing.

When I export as a PDF it looks perfect.
When I view it in Internet Explorer, there are double lines / gaps between the lines around each cell etc.
When I export to Word the size of the cells are wrong - cell height has changed  for every cell
When I export to Excel the 2nd table (far right one) thinks it should be one row higher than the rest.

I was thinking I could just select everything and hit the 'align to grid' button, but it is disabled.

Comment: Some export formats are more picky than others. Use the location and size properties to make sure things are positioned exactly where they should be.

Comment: Other than re-editing it, I didn't see how to revert it, (I may not be at that level yet) and with everyone approving the change, I didn't see the point - this is the first question I've ever had anyone edit.  (I noticed that you also removed the version information from my other post about SSRS - granted, it might apply to all version, but it is ALWAYS good to include the version information in a post!